# Splitting the redux state where some variables are common

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux-toolkit for my chat application. Currently there are two slices in the store:

- userSlice - for managing the user state

  ```
  import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
  import appApi from "../services/appApi";

  const endpoints = [
    appApi.endpoints.signUpUser,
    appApi.endpoints.loginUser,
    appApi.endpoints.profileUser,
    appApi.endpoints.logout,
  ];

  export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState: {
      loading: false,
      error: null,
      _id: null,
    },
    reducers: {
      addNotifications: (state, { payload }) => {},
      resetNotifications: (state, { payload }) => {},
      clearError: (state) => {
        state.error = null;
        state.loading = false;
      },
      setError: (state,{payload}) =>
      {
        state.error = payload
      },
      loadID: (state) => {
        state._id =
          JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cherry-chat-status")) || null;
      },
      setLoading: (state, { payload }) =>
      {
        state.loading = payload
      }
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
      builder.addMatcher(
        appApi.endpoints.signUpUser.matchFulfilled,
        (state, { payload }) => {
          localStorage.setItem("cherry-chat-status", JSON.stringify(payload._id));

          return { ...state, loading: false, error: null, ...payload };
        }
      );


      builder.addMatcher(
        appApi.endpoints.loginUser.matchFulfilled,
        (state, { payload }) => {
          localStorage.setItem("cherry-chat-status", JSON.stringify(payload._id));
          return { ...state, loading: false, error: null, ...payload };
        }
      );
      builder.addMatcher(
        appApi.endpoints.profileUser.matchFulfilled,
        (state, { payload }) =>
        {

          return { ...state, loading: false, error: null, ...payload };
        }
      );

      builder.addMatcher(
        appApi.endpoints.profileUser.matchFulfilled,
        (state, { payload }) => {
          return { ...state, loading: false, error: null, ...payload };
        }
      );
      builder.addMatcher(appApi.endpoints.logout.matchFulfilled, () => {
        localStorage.removeItem("cherry-chat-status");

        return { loading: false, error: null };
      });

      endpoints.forEach(({ matchPending, matchRejected }) => {
        builder.addMatcher(matchPending, (state) => {
          state.loading = true;
          state.error = null;
        });
        builder.addMatcher(matchRejected, (state, { payload: error }) => {
          state.error = error?.data?.message;
          state.loading = false;
        });
      });
    },
  });

  export const {
    addNotifications,
    resetNotifications,
    clearError,
    loadID,
    setError,
    setLoading,
  } = userSlice.actions;

  export default userSlice.reducer;
  ```
- messageSlice - for managing the messages

  ```
  import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
  import io from "socket.io-client";
  import msgApi from "../services/msgApi";

  const SOCKET_URL = "localhost:5000";

  export const socket = io(SOCKET_URL);

  const endpoints = [msgApi.endpoints.profileUserRooms];

  export const messageSlice = createSlice({
    name: "message",
    initialState: {
      rooms: [],
      currentRoom: [],
      members: [],
      messages: [],
      privateMemberMsg: {},
      newMessages: {},
      error: null,
    },
    reducers: {
      addMembers: (state, { payload }) => {
        state.members = payload;
      },
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
      // your extra reducers go here

      builder.addMatcher(
        msgApi.endpoints.profileUserRooms.matchFulfilled,
        (state, { payload }) => {

  //I want set the loading state of the user Slice to be false
          return {
            ...state,
            rooms: payload,
          };
        }
      );
      endpoints.forEach(({ matchPending, matchRejected }) => {
        builder.addMatcher(matchPending, (state) => {
          state.error = null;

  //I want set the loading state of the user Slice to be true 
        });
        builder.addMatcher(matchRejected, (state, { payload: error }) => {
          state.error = error?.data?.message;

  //I want set the loading state of the user Slice to be false
        });
      });
    },
  });

  export const { addMembers } = messageSlice.actions;
  export default messageSlice.reducer;
  ```

Is there any method such that I can access the loading and error from the user slice and can be set at the messageSlice also? Or should I change the structure of the state or should I duplicate those variables in both slices?

Comment: You can dispatch an action from the messageSlice that updates the loading state in the userSlice. To do this, you'll need to import the setLoading action from the userSlice and dispatch it with the appropriate value in the extraReducers of the messageSlice.

Comment: You can access the entire state in thunk actions and dispatch actions that are handled in any reducer/slice. In your case actions like `msgApi.endpoints.profileUserRooms` shouldn't be dispatched directly, you need a wrapper around that waits for `matchFulfilled`. That can either be a thunk or just a function you call in your components. tl;dr you need to coordinate this outside of reducers. When the action reaches a specific reducer/slice it is already too late.

Comment: @SmbatPoghosyan You cannot dispatch actions in `extraReducers`. From the docs: "extraReducers allows createSlice to respond to other action types besides the types it has generated". `extraReducers` would work as a workaround for OPs case. In my personal opinion though it deviates a bit too far from the core principles of redux. It's harder to reason about slices if they're involved with actions from other slices.

Comment: @timotgl : fwiw we _explicitly encourage_ that many reducers should respond to the same action, as a good architectural principle: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#model-actions-as-events-not-setters , https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action

Comment: @markerikson I wasn't aware of this, thanks for pointing it out. Looks like `extraReducers` is a legitimate solution then.